# scala module after sbt installation

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-breeze

May I ask some newbie question here:

My goal is to use Breeze module (0.10) in Scala (2.11.5), and I follow:

```
$ sbt
set scalaVersion := "2.10.3" // or 2.11.3
set libraryDependencies += "org.scalanlp" %% "breeze" % "0.10"
set resolvers += "Sonatype Releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
console
```

and actually, it ran well, and at the end, when I got the prompt I can do this well (some example from the Breeze site)

```
import breeze.linalg._
```

However, after I exit and re-enter Scala by just

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_75).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

and with some excitement, I tried:

```
scala> import breeze.linalg._
<console>:7: error: not found: value breeze
       import breeze.linalg._
              ^
```

It seems the module is "gone" after the installation ...
May I know how to get "Breeze" installed permanently? or did I miss any linkage here?

Your answer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The scala/java ecosystem just doesn't work that way; the global classpath doesn't get changed because some project uses a jar.

Your easiest solution is to just make a bash alias (e.g. brscala) that invokes the same sbt incantation.

There are ways to make it work (involving putting symlinks to breeze and all of its dependencies in $SCALA_HOME/lib), but that's definitely not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to access the libraries from the Terminal

- Specify the dependencies (here breeze & saddle) in build.sbt, e.g.

  ```
  scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

  resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Sonatype OSS Releases" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/",
  "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/",
  "Sonatype Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/",
  "Sonatype Releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
  )

   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.1",
   "org.joda" % "joda-convert" % "1.2",
   "org.scala-saddle" %% "saddle-core" % "1.3.+",
   "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.4.1" % "test",
   "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.11.3" % "test",
   "junit" % "junit" % "4.11" % "test",
   "org.scalanlp" %% "breeze" % "0.12",
   "org.scalanlp" %% "breeze-natives" % "0.12",
   "org.scalanlp" %% "breeze-viz" % "0.12"
  )

  initialCommands := """
  import org.joda.time.DateTime
  import org.saddle._
  import org.saddle.time._
  import org.saddle.io._
  import me.first_install_saddle._
  import breeze.linalg._"""
  ```
- Assuming you are cd into the directory of build.sbt: run `sbt update` to install the dependencies
- Then instead of just `scala`, run `sbt console` in Terminal

From there you can access the libraries from the Terminal.